# Problemas com SQL e cursor

Tags: sql

Não percebo porquê mas o meu código SQL está a dar erro na linha do FETCH, mais concretamente: 'FETCH NEXT FROM c_cursor INTO @idC, @LIT, @LST, @LST, @LIT;' , e eu não percebo a razão deste erro. Estou a tentar fazer um cursor para percorrer a tabela cultura (já existente) e fazer uma verficação relacionada com os campos in do procedure, mas por alguma razão aparece-me este erro: 'The procedure 'Alerta (DBA)' could not be modified in the database. Syntax error near 'FETCH' on line 14'. Se alguém conseguisse ajudar agradecia.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."Alerta"(IN Temperatura DECIMAL, IN Humidade DECIMAL)
BEGIN

DECLARE @idC INTEGER;
DECLARE @LIT DECIMAL;
Declare @LST DECIMAL;
DECLARE @LSH DECIMAL;
DECLARE @LIH DECIMAL;


DECLARE c_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT IDCultura, LimiteInferiorTemperatura, LimiteSuperiorTemperatura, LimiteSuperiorHumidade, LimiteInferiorHumidade FROM Cultura;
OPEN c_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM c_cursor INTO @idC, @LIT, @LST, @LST, @LIT;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN;
    IF (@LST < new_temp.ValorMedicaoTemperatura OR new_temp.ValorMedicaoTemperatura > @LIT)
        INSERT INTO Alertas(IDAlerta, DataMedicao, ValorMedicao, NomeVariavel, IDCultura)
        VALUES 
        (now(), new_temp.ValorMedicaoTemperatura, 'Temp', @idC); 

    IF (@LSH < new_temp.ValorMedicaoHumidade OR new_temp.ValorMedicaoHumidade > @LIH)
        INSERT INTO Alertas(IDAlerta, DataMedicao, ValorMedicao, NomeVariavel, IDCultura)
        VALUES 
        (now(), new_temp.ValorMedicaoHumidade, 'Hum', @idC); 

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_cursor INTO @idC, @LIT, @LST, @LST, @LIT;

END;
CLOSE c_cursor;
DEALLOCATE c_cursor;
```

END

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o ponto-e-vírgula em

```
OPEN c_cursor;
```

Veja um exemplo [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#a-using-fetch-in-a-simple-cursor).